# How can we pass parameters to Alpine.data in Alpine.js v3?

Tags: alpine.js

I am now using the newest version of Alpine which is v3.

Making reusable components needs to be registered using the `Alpine.data`.

This is the `alpinejs.js`

```js
import Alpine from 'alpinejs'
import form from './components/form'

window.Alpine = Alpine

Alpine.data('form', form)

Alpine.start()
```

This is what I have in the components/form.js

```js
export default (config) => {
  return {
    open: false,
    init() {
      console.log(config)
    },
    get isOpen() { return this.open },
    close() { this.open = false },
    open() { this.open = true },
  }
}
```

This is the html part:

```html
<div x-data="form({test:'test'})"></div>
```

This is the error I get in the console:

[image: Alpine.js Console Error]

Any idea how to pass parameters to Alpine.data?

Comment: I would like to know the official way for this as well since before with Alpine v2 I have used functions with parameters to generate and return needed x-data objects.

At the moment with V3 I think you could define a `start(config)` function in you component and use `<div x-data="form" x-init="start({test:'test'})"></div>`

Comment: Ran into the same thing. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled over this question, searching for an answer but figured it out now. Maybe its still usefull to someone...

You have do define the parameter when registering the data component:

```js
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {

    window.Alpine.data('myThing', (param) => MyModule(param));

});
```

Now you can use it in your module on init...

```js
export default (param) => ({
    init() {
        console.log(param);
    }
});
```

... when you init the component

```html
<div x-data="deliveryDate({ foo: 'bar' })"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This likely happens since you imported your script as a module. Therefore, you need another script that handles initialization of data.

I'm using a *vanillajs vite setup* and here's a working implementation with alpinejs:

`index.html`

```html
<head>
    <!-- Notice the type="module" part -->
    <script type="module" src="/main.js" defer></script>

    <script src="/initializer.js"></script>
</head>

<body x-data="greetingState">
  <button @click="changeText">
    <span x-text="message"></span>
  </button>

  <h2 x-text="globalNumber"></h2>
</body>
```

`main.js`

```js
import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.Alpine = Alpine;
Alpine.start();

// const globalNumber = 10; // Wrong place
```

`initialize.js`

```js
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('greetingState', () => ({
    message: "Hello World!",

    changeText() {
      this.message = "Hello AlpineJs!";
    },
  }));
});

const globalNumber = 10; // Correct place
```

Note that listening to the `alpine:init` custom event inside of a javascript module will break the app. The same happens if you try to display a variable from a script of type module, in this example `globalNumber`.